# How do I do the manual set up of MinGW in my computer?

Tags: windows-8, mingw

**My problem:** I have been trying to install `MinGW` manually but I cannot find the `PATH` it says that I needed to modify.

**MinGW site says:**

1. Right-click on your "My Computer" icon and select "Properties".
2. Click on the "Advanced" tab, then on the "Environment Variables" button.
3. You should be presented with a dialog box with two text boxes. The top box shows your user settings. The PATH entry in this box is the one you want to modify. Note that the bottom text box allows you to change the system PATH variable. You should not alter the system path variable in any manner, or you will cause all sorts of problems for you and your computer!
4. Click on the **PATH entry in the TOP box, then click on the "Edit" button**
5. Scroll to the end of the string and at the end add

   ```
   ;<installation-directory>\bin
   ```
6. press OK -> OK -> OK and you are done.

Again, my problem is that I cannot find the ***PATH*** in the TOP box (User). There are only two items in the top box (`TEMP` and `TMP`) of my computer. Can anyone tell me what to do? I'm using Windows 8 by the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you can Press "New..." and create your own PATH by fill in the Variable name with PATH and Variable value of your PATH.

Btw, I tried to manually install MingGW but there is not easy and there are some tricks that you won't success without knowing them. I suggest at least you read [this instructions](http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html) before you do your own.

Comment: I think it is better to copy the PATH value from the system variables and extend it in the user variables.